# How do xanthan gum and other hydrocolloids work?

Tags: water, solutions, colloids

Does anyone know what causes things like xanthan gum to make water into a slimy substance on the molecular level?

Comment: What you are essentially asking is: "what is the cause of non-newtonian behaviour in hydrocolloid solutions?" This is a very good question, but it has an extremely complex answer. Maybe the best place to start is to read this article: http://www.sciencemag.org/content/333/6047/1276.full

Comment: Also check out pages 21 and 22 of this document: http://www3.imperial.ac.uk/pls/portallive/docs/1/40246.PDF